# How to stop the media player automatically within 5 seconds in android

Tags: android

```
 final MediaPlayer carSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.car_alarm_going_off);

        Button panicsound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnpanic);
        panicsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                carSoundMP.start();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a count down time, or handler.

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        carSoundMP.stop();
　　　　carSoundMP.release();
　　　　carSoundMP = null;
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: The above code works for my apps..but there is a pop up say that "Unfortunately, ECButton has stopped" when i clicked the button for second time.. how  I want to fix it? Thank you for your time to answer my question

Comment: Do you want mediaplayer to stop immediately, or do you want the mediaplayer to wait 5 seconds before stopping?  You may want to keep a boolean variable that stores whether a stop button has been clicked.  If stop button has not been clicked, then the CountDownTimer can run.

Comment: I want the button play the mediaplayer within 5 seconds and stop automatically and I can press it  the button again.

Answer (score 0):

final MediaPlayer carSoundMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.car_alarm_going_off);
        Button panicsound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnpanic);

```
    panicsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            carSoundMP.start();

        }

    });

   new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            carSoundMP.stop();
            carSoundMP.release();
           // carSoundMP = null;
        }

    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling stop() on mpfrog if you are playing audio with carSoundMP ? You need to call the stop() function on the carSoundMP MediaPlayer. Also, you might want to add the @Override annotation to your onClick() method.

for the override...

```
panicsound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                carSoundMP.start();{
                    sleep(2000);
                    carSoundMP.stop();
                }
            }
        });
```

for a timer.....

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                carSoundMP.stop();
            }
        };

//Task for timer to execute when time expires
    class SleepTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

//then in some other function...
Timer timer = new Timer("timer",true);
timer.schedule(new SleepTask(),2000);
```

Comment: it is not work for me..should I need to create class for handler method?